# Codeigniter Search between dates and more parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I'm trying to implement a search engine on my page, I want to search for tickets using these parameters:

1. Ticket# and/or
2. Scope/Keyword (Any word or character inside the ticket description) and/or
3. Between 2 dates, Starting Date and Ending Date

The search function in my model goes like this:

```
function search($id,$scope,$start_date,$end_date)
    {
        if (!empty($id) || !empty($scope)){
        $this->db->like('TROUBLE_ID', $id);
        $this->db->or_like('PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION', $scope);
        $this->db->where('ASSIGNED_DATE >=', $start_date);
        $this->db->where('ASSIGNED_DATE <=', $end_date); 
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db);
        return $query->result_array();
        }
        else {echo 'No results to display';}
    }
```

My controller function:

```
function search_keyword()
    {           
        //Search Engine
        $id = $this->input->post('ID');
        $scope = $this->input->post('SCOPE');
        $start_date = $this->input->post('STARTING_DATE');
        $end_date = $this->input->post('ENDING_DATE');
        $data['results']    =   $this->rfi_model->search($id,$scope,$start_date,$end_date);
        $this->load->view('ticketSearchParameters',$data);

    }
```

And the View Results page:

```
<?php
foreach($results as $row){
    $id = $row['TROUBLE_ID'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['TROUBLE_ID']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ASSIGNED_DATE']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['CREATOR']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['RESOLUTION']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['RESOLVED_DATE']?></td>            
    </tr>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

But somehow the search is not coming right, It doesnt work if i leave the ticket# field empty and is not filtering the tickets between those 2 dates also. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work if you leave the ticket# field empty, bcz there is a condition,
`if (!empty($id) || !empty($scope)){`

Comment: I use that condition for testing purposes, even if I delete it, it doesnt work

Comment: Did you try $this->db->last_query()?

Comment: Im using `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` and is showing that no queries were made

Answer (score 1):

try to debug using

```
$this->db->last_query()
```

and then try that sql directly in phpmyadmin, this will help you find the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having two different problems. My guess about the date search not working is that they are not in yyyy-mm-dd format, which is what MySQL requires for comparison.

It doesn't work if you leave ID blank because you do not exclude this line from your condition on a blank ID.

```
    $this->db->like('TROUBLE_ID', $id);
```

So, if you leave a blank ID blank, but that line is always included, you are asking MySQL to only return rows with blank IDs.

This is one way you could solve it. I eliminated a parameter for this example because if you know the id you probably don't need a keyword as well, and also to make the example more simple.

```
function search($id_or_scope, $start_date, $end_date)
    {
        if (!empty($id_or_scope))
        {
          if (is_numeric($id_or_scope))
            $this->db->like('TROUBLE_ID', $id_or_scope);
          else
            $this->db->like('PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION', $id_or_scope);

          $this->db->where('ASSIGNED_DATE >=', $start_date);
          $this->db->where('ASSIGNED_DATE <=', $end_date); 
          $query = $this->db->get($this->db);
          return $query->result_array();
        }
        else {echo 'No results to display';}
    }
```

Comment: I like your approach, but from where that `$id_or_scope` comes from?

Comment: Also all the fields are optional, with or without, and I think thats my problem, because if I leave any field blank all the records are shown

Comment: if they are all optional, then you will need an if statement for every parameter. If the parameter is blank, do not include the db->where clause for that parameter. In my example the $id_or_scope would ceom from the manner in which you call the method of  $this->rfi_model->search($id_or_scope,$start_date,$end_date);  Your own original code would also work fine if you make an if check for each parameter to check if it is blank before including it in the db class.

Comment: If they are all optional, then you can wrap each where or like clause in an if conditional and this will omit comparisons to blank values.